# ImportError: cannot import name 'get_terminal_size' from 'click.termui'

Tags: python, python-3.x, typer

Using python lib [typer](https://github.com/tiangolo/typer) throws an error.

some of the depended stacktrace:

```sh
   ...
  import typer
  File "/builds/.../.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typer/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
  from click.termui import get_terminal_size as get_terminal_size
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_terminal_size' from 'click.termui' (/builds/.../.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/termui.py)
```

Answer (score 5):

Ah sry, i had to update to the latest version `0.4.1`.

Depended pr: https://github.com/tiangolo/typer/pull/375

(Only leave this answer if anyone makes the same mistake.)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

###### uninstall and reinstall `ipython`

`pip uninstall ipython` OR `pip3 uninstall ipython`

`pip install ipython` OR `pip3 install ipython`

next write this

###### if you are using on terminal/shell

`pip install typer --upgrade` OR
`pip3 install typer --upgrade`

###### if pip is not in PATH environment variable

`python -m pip install typer --upgrade` OR
`python3 -m pip install typer --upgrade`

###### if you are working on Jupyter Notebook or Google Colab

`!pip install typer --upgrade`

(PS:- `pip` is a soft link for a particular installer. `pip3` is an updated version of pip which is used basically for python 3+.)